# Can't create a new tube in Pheanstalk

Tags: php, beanstalkd, pheanstalk

I am using Pheanstalk, and I want to create a new tube on an existing queue, so I wrote the following code:

```
$this->pheanstalk = new Pheanstalk(127.0.0.1);
$this->pheanstalk->useTube('api')->put($json_info, 0,0,1); //json_info is data that i need to put in a tube as json encoded
```

But when I run the following command to check the tube:

```
$ telnet localhost 11300 
list-tubes
```

This is what I always get:

```
OK 14
- default
```

Why isn't the 'api' tube being created? Is there something I should do to see the 'api' tube in the list?

Comment: Does your original code also have the parameter to the constructor as a number? Also, add "error_reporting(-1);" to the script, and see if it complains about the unquoted string.

Comment: The IP address (127.0.0.1) should also be quoted - '127.0.0.1'. Add some debugging and catch any exceptions to see what the errors may be.

Answer (score -1):

The tube is created from the side of the workers, using the watch function